# How to fix build error when running "react-native run-windows"

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, mobile, windows-10-universal

Here is the result on prompt. I'm using a Windows 10 virtual machine inside Ubuntu and I already downloaded the dependencies in Visual Studio as the documentation says.

```
 √ Found NuGet Binary
 √ Restoring NuGets
 √ Found MSBuild v16.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin

 √ Found Solution: C:/Users/aders/Development/react/windowsapp/windows/windowsapp.sln

  Build configuration: Debug  
  Build platform: x86

 × Building Solution: Projeto de compila��o pronto "C:\Users\aders\Development\react\windowsapp\windows\windowsap..." Here have just a little bit of Portuguese, but it says that the compilation is ready, but it does not work, as you can see.

 × Build failed with message undefined. Check your build configuration.
```

Comment: There are some [issues](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/consuming-rnw#running-a-react-native-windows-app) with msbuild with `react-native run-windows`. you could try using Visual Studio or VS Code to build.

Comment: _Check your build configuration._ so what is your build configuration?

Comment: Where do I check my build config?